# Running a block of code in the background of AppleScriptObjC app?

Tags: background, applescript, repeat, applescript-objc

Is it possible to have a block of code constantly running or 'repeating' in AppleScriptObjC, whilst the rest of your script is still active?  I've got a block of code that I want to repeat in the background that checks to see if a folder exists and creates it if it doesn't, but if I set it to repeat indefinitely then I lose the ability to access the other buttons and code blocks in my app?

Apologies if there isn't enough info here or it's a bit confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a repeating NSTimer to do the check at a specified interval. That would avoid blocking your main thread.

Depending on the app, perhaps you could also just check for the existence of the folder and create it just in time, when you really have a need for it.